# Tools for Performance Testing Grails Wep Applications

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, grails, firebird

I am searching for an Tool to test an Grails Wep Application on a Tomcat Server.

I need some Data about the Performance when 30 Users work with my app.(Creating/Editing/Deleting Entries on my Database (Firebird).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of web performance testing tools.

You can use

- [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)
- [PushToTest](http://www.pushtotest.com)

Or if you want a cheap load testing service provider have a look at [BrowserMob](http://browsermob.com). They run load testing on demand for people and their rates are quite reasonable.

Comment: PushToTest and BrowserMob can load test AJAX applications

Answer (score 1):

To monitor [Firebird performance](http://www.sinatica.com): [www.sinatica.com](http://www.sinatica.com)

Comment: for new Firebird Databases is really great.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firebird 2.1 or higher you can use [sinactica monitor](http://www.sinactica.com) but for older server you can look here http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq95/

[IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com) also have a monitor tool

You can find good tools for firebird at [www.ib-aid.com](http://www.ib-aid.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can run through some rudimentary tests, that can then be exported to JMeter with BadBoy http://www.badboy.com.au

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out ApacheBench? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html